# How to calculate attr.cx without stringification in angular template

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a svg diagram, but for my my circles i would like to add 0.5 on their cx and cy with [attr.cy] and [attr.cx] my problem is that it stringify the values i set so example.

```
<svg>
    <circle [attr.cx]="x+width"></circle>
</svg>
```

so if x=40 and width=50 the result becomes 4050, it does not actually calculate the sizes, same happend if in the component i create a getter

```
@Input()
x=40;
@Input()
width=50;
get westx(){
    // returns 5040 in template
    return this.width+this.x;
}
```

weird thing is it can do subtractions so to make its adding in the template i subtract twice, but that cant really be the right solution, unless that is just a weird bug that allows subtractions.

```
<svg>
    <circle [attr.cx]="x--width"></circle>
</svg>
```

setting values directly on cx and cy is not possible on the template those are readonly, so i can only set them via attr.

Comment: have you tried parsing to `int`?

Comment: that is how javascript strings work. you should convert it to int. the simplest way is to do it just in place `[attr.cx]="+x + +width`. as unar plus sign converts to integer in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your values are concatenated but rather calculated is due to strings ("5" + "5" = 55) . Try casting your values to `int`

```
get westx(){
 // returns 5040 in template
  return parseInt(width, 10) + parseInt(x, 10);
}
```

**Update**

Since you have declared `width` and `x` as `number` which will throw an error while casting to `integer`, in order to avoid that, cast the variables to `string` first and then `int`

```
get westx(){
 
  return parseInt(width.toString(), 10) + parseInt(x.toString(), 10);
}
```

Comment: sadly  it wont allow me to parse numbers to int

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen try this then `return parseInt(width.toString(), 10) + parseInt(x.toString(), 10);`

Comment: works. i wonder if it comes from my input that is a string